# How to check git status when moving massive folders?

Tags: git

I just changed hierarchy of my project, moving a folder that contains tens thousands of files total, and ran `git add --all`. `git status` command is useless now - it prints out thousands of lines, too huge to read through.

What's the best way to check the state of the staging area before committing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git detects file renames by comparing every pair of file removes/additions, which is O(n<sup>2</sup>). To keep computation time low, it will not try to detect renames if there are too many files.

Try `git diff -l0 --name-status --cached HEAD`:

- `-l0` sets the limit for rename detection to some very high number
- `--name-status` to simply print out a status for each file, for example

  ```
  R100    old_name    new_name
  ```

  indicating that `old_name` is removed and `new_name` is added with 100% matching content
- `--cached HEAD` to compare the last commit and the current stage. You can leave out `--cached` to compare the last commit and the current working tree, which should be the same following `git add -A/--all`.

There is additionally `-C --find-copies-harder` for copy detection.